# $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\sinh(x)-\sin(x)}{x(\cosh(x)-\cos(x))}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, trigonometry

As stated in the title.

My attempt, begin with L'Hopital:
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\sinh(x)-\sin(x)}{x(\cosh(x)-\cos(x))}}=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\cosh(x)-\cos(x)}{(\cosh(x)-\cos(x))+x(\sinh(x)+\sin(x))}}$$
Dividing by the numerator
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{x\left(\sinh(x)+\sin(x)\right)}{\cosh(x)-\cos(x)}\right)}=\frac{1}{1+\lim_{x \to 0}{\left(\frac{x\left(\sinh(x)+\sin(x)\right)}{\cosh(x)-\cos(x)}\right)}}$$
L'Hopital again
$$\frac{1}{1+\lim_{x \to 0}{\left(\frac{x(\cosh(x)+\cos(x))+(\sinh(x)+\sin(x))}{\sinh(x)+\sin(x)}\right)}}$$
Diving through
$$\frac{1}{1+\lim_{x \to 0}{\left(1+\frac{\cosh(x)+\cos(x)}{\left(\frac{\sinh(x)}{x}+\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right)}\right)}}=\frac{1}{1+(1+\frac{1+1}{1+1})}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Is this correct, and is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: In fact,
\begin{eqnarray}
L&=&\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\sinh(x)-\sin(x)}{x(\cosh(x)-\cos(x))}}\\
&=&\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\sinh(x)-\sin(x)}{x^3}}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{x^2}{\cosh(x)-\cos(x)}}\\
&=&\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\cosh(x)-\cos(x)}{3x^2}}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{2x}{\sinh(x)+\sin(x)}}
\end{eqnarray}
and you can continue.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sinh x-\sin x\sim\tfrac13x^3$ while $\cosh x-\cos x\sim x^2$, the limit is $\tfrac13$.

Answer (score 2):

It looks fine, but I would have done it as follows\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sinh(x)-\sin(x)}{x\bigl(\cosh(x)-\cos(x)\bigr)}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left(x+\frac{x^3}6+o(x^4)\right)-\left(x-\frac{x^3}6+o(x^4)\right)}{x\left(\left(1+\frac{x^2}2+o(x^3)\right)-\left(1-\frac{x^2}2+o(x^3)\right)\right)}\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{x^3}3+o(x^4)}{x+o(x^4)}\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac13+o(x^3)}{1+o(x^3)}\\&=\frac13.\end{align}